# How to centralize the tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have made a table like this

```
\documentclass[notuble,10pt,a4paper]{leaflet}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,eqparbox,tabularx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\newenvironment{tips}
{
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{m{0.2cm} m{\textwidth}}
\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{FISAT}}}&
}
{\end{tabular}
\bigskip
}

\begin{document}


\begin{tips}
\begin{tabular}{l}
{\resizebox{5cm}{!}{ONE}}\\ 
{\resizebox{5cm}{!}{MILLION}}\\ 
{\resizebox{5cm}{!}{CODES TO}} \\ 
{\resizebox{5cm}{!}{THE COMMUNITY}}\
\end{tabular} 
\end{tips}

\end{document}
```

How could I centralize this

Comment: You could put `\hfill` 's around the outer tabular. That would require you to change the second `m` column to a width other than `\textwidth` though, since otherwise the centering won't really appear to do anything.

Comment: also, for an MWE there are a lot of commented lines and unused packages in your code. Not to mention the superfluous `\end{document}`. Try to keep MWE's *minimal*. In this case it's not a real problem, but it's a good general rule. since removing packages can sometimes help you diagnose the problem yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `leaflet` class, the reason why you have three columns on that page. See the horizontal line which shows you that the tabular is centered in the right column. If you want the tabular in the middle column (centered over all columns) then put the table into the middle column. Needs some more text or five `\null\clearpage` before the tabular.

```
\documentclass[notuble,10pt,a4paper]{leaflet}
\usepackage{rotating}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newenvironment{tips}{\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c  | c |}
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\rotatebox{90}{%
  \textbf{\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{FISAT}}}} & }
{\end{tabular}\end{center}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tips}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\resizebox{5cm}{!}{ONE}\\ 
\resizebox{5cm}{!}{MILLION}\\ 
\resizebox{5cm}{!}{CODES TO} \\ 
\resizebox{5cm}{!}{THE COMMUNITY}\

\end{tabular} 
\end{tips}

\noindent
\rule{\linewidth}{3pt}

\end{document}
```